# Set contentContainerStyle of specific element

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a FlatList in React Native and I have to set the z-Index of the nth content container to 2, so it overlaps every following container. Is there a way to achieve this behavior?

I need something like this I believe:

```js
<FlatList contentContainerStyle={index => ({zIndex: index === 2 ? 1 : 0})} {...} />
```

The problem is, I don't know a way to get access to the index when defining the style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found this solution [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28751):

```js
const renderCell = useCallback(
  ({ index, style, ...props }) => {
      const zIndex = {
        zIndex: index === draggedItem ? 2 : 0,
    };

    return <View style={[style, zIndex]} {...props} />;
  },
  [draggedItem],
);
```

```js
<FlatList CellRendererComponent={renderCell}/>
```